# How to fetch complete data from the database's table through RMI using the array method?

Tags: java, rmi

I want to fetch complete data from the database's table through RMI. I used the array method in the Java interface and I have implemented that method in  implementation class. My intention is to take the data in the array via implementation and show it via `JTable` on the client side. I have created a one-column table in the database. I have to get that whole data from that table to the client side.

I have attached the coding that I did.
I have commented the errors in the code section that I got.

**interface**

```
public interface Interface extends Remote {
     public static String[] getArray() throws Remote Exception; // Here it shows missing method 
                                                               //  body or declare abstract
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class TheImplementation extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Interface{
    
    public TheImplementation()throws Remote Exception{
        super();
    }
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3763231206310559L;
    
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rst;

    public static String[] getArray() throws RemoteException{
        String fruitdetails = null; 
        try {
            Connection connection=ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
            Statement st=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select *from details");
            while(rs.next()) { 
                fruitdetails= rs.getString("fruit");
                String tbData[]={fruitdetails};
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return tbData;// Here it shows error. Cannot find symbol.
                           // I tried to declare array at top. But, It didn't work.
    }
}
```

Comment: `tbData` is declared in the while loop, so it's scope is only within the while loop.  Your sql will throw an error when you get this to compile.  Other `Interface` is not a good name for a Java Object.  `con` `pst` and `rst` are declared but never used.  Why have `getArray` as a `static` method and why bother to interface it?

Comment: Connection, Statement and ResultSet are never closed. JOptionPane is used on server side to display error messages.

Comment: Refer to [Java doc for Scope of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867972/java-doc-for-scope-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract methods in [remote interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/designing.html) cannot be static, so you need to change the interface definition to the following.

```java
public interface Interface extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public String[] getArray() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Values returned by remote methods must be [serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html). Arrays in java are serializable, however arrays have a fixed size and since you are returning the result of a database query you cannot know the size. Hence I suggest that method `getArray` return an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) or better yet, a [CachedRowSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html).

```java
public interface Interface extends Remote {
    public CachedRowSet getArray() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Since class `TheImplementation` is your RMI server class, it is probably better to [log](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/core/java-logging-overview.html) exceptions rather than display a `JOptionPane` and you should always log the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). Note that remote methods must declare that they throw `RemoteException` in order to inform the RMI client that the remote method failed. Hence apart from logging the exception, method `getArray` can also throw a `RemoteException`.

The following code demonstrates.

```java
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;

public class TheImplementation extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Interface {

    public TheImplementation() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3763231206310559L;

    public CachedRowSet getArray() throws RemoteException {
        try (Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
             Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from details")) {
            RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
            CachedRowSet fruitDetails = factory.createCachedRowSet();
            fruitDetails.populate(rs);
            return fruitDetails;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RemoteException("Method 'getArray()' failed.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above code also uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that the `ResultSet`, `Statement` and `Connection` are all closed.